# 2006 Chevrolet Express 3500: Torque Converter Replacement

Tags: chevrolet, express-van, ls

I have a 2006 Chevrolet Express 3500 LT, short-wheelbase, 6.0l LQ4 V8. With the 4L80E transmission. Recently, I had the torque converter stop locking. The only torque converter from the local auto-parts stores is a $150 one from a brand I've never heard of. I'd rather stay away from it if possible. An OEM torque converter is $600-$700 depending on the retailer.

So, I want to go aftermarket. Specifically one from a reputable retailer, such as Jegs or Summit Racing. I want one with a higher stall than stock (I think stock is 1800 RPM).

This is the one I am looking at https://www.summitracing.com/parts/ape-49482

However, it says that there are two different impeller hub lengths. One is 2", the other is 2.5". But I cannot find the info anywhere; this is my last resort before I take the transmission out to find it. I hope someone could provide insight into this matter.

Thanks,
Conrad

Comment: The one I'm seeing is 2.050" hub height. I don't think the one you showed from Summit is one you really want. It's stall speed is 2200-2800 RPM. Typical stall speed of a stock converter should be around 1800 RPM. If your transmission isn't tuned for it, it'll most likely drive you nutty. If I were you, I'd get a remanufactured converter. It will have the correct stall speed as well as have new innards. Should work perfectly for your needs. I also see a brand new OEM converter (yes, GM one) for the same price as the aftermarket brand you show (which I've never heard of, btw).

Comment: In which ways will it mess with the transmission? I was told it would improve off the line power.

Comment: It can mess with shifting. Also, it doesn't "improve off the line power", it allows the engine to spin higher to get to the stall point, which is where the transmission engages at. This puts the engine into a higher torque range. Usually a torque converter is matched to the camshaft. Larger cam, higher stall speed. You'd contact the torque converter manufacturer to match the two. The other tradeoff is, higher stall, greater fuel consumption. If you're dead set on getting a Boss Hog converter, look at the 49480. It is for stock stall speed and is cheaper.